# htaccess rewrite get variable issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My 5th and 6th rules that are commented out do not do anything and not sure of any other way to try to get my result. I am looking to make mysite.us/item.php?id=1 display as mysite.us/item/1

Currently my url ends up being mysite.us/item?id=1

Also maybe someone can help me clean this up a bit as its fairly new to me.

A couple things: godaddy server, im using extension-less links (not sure if this is correct but it was the only way ajax would continue to work)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# Makes sure www is not in url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.us/$1 [R=301]

# Removes index.php from url to only display homepage
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://mysite.us/ [R=301]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://mysite/$1 [R=301]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://mysite.us/$1 [R=301]

#RewriteRule ^item/([^/.]+)/?$ item.php?id=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^.+/item/([0-9]+) item.php?id=$1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

***UPDATE***
OK so I knew I was new to rewriting but now I feel very noobish and will show the mistakes I made to hopefully help save time for someone in the future. Because of this I must point out that the answer provided me below does actually work and is a great solution. My 5th and 6th rule also now work.

I was under the impression that the rewrite cleaned up my URL from the link I provide.
Instead I am to provide the clean URL in the link and the rewrite rule provides the desired file. From a security stand point this makes perfect sense, but I only desired a clean URL.

Also all my head files like js and css need to be absolute URLs unlike I was taught.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)$ /item.php?id=$1&%1 [L]
```

This also captures any query string you might add later (i.e. `/item/1?foo=bar`)